# Moving files from 1 directory to another

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am trying to print all the files names in all the directories in my computer ...
I have taken help from a code which is written by @mayur
I want this to run for my whole computer ...
as in it should cover my whole computer so i want that path to be dynamic to cover all the drives.....

I am taking help from a code ...
But in this i have to give a path ....
I want this to run for my whole computer ...
as in it should cover my whole computer so i want that path to be dynamic to cover all the drives.....

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <TCHAR.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Enum(TCHAR root[0xFF])
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    TCHAR GeneralPath[0xFF];
    TCHAR AgainFolder[0xFF];
    TCHAR FileFullPath[0xFF];

    _stprintf(GeneralPath, _T("%s\\*.*"), root);
    hFind = FindFirstFile(GeneralPath, &wfd);

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE==hFind)
        return;

    do
    {
        if( wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) //Checking Founded File Attribute is it File or Folder/Directory
        {
            if( !_tcscmp(wfd.cFileName, _T(".")) || !_tcscmp(wfd.cFileName, _T("..")) ) //if Founded directory is same(.) or parent(..) then ignore them
                continue;
            _stprintf(AgainFolder, _T("%s\\%s"), root, wfd.cFileName);
            Enum(AgainFolder); //Recursion because folder is inside another folder
        }
        else
        {
            _stprintf(FileFullPath, _T("%s\\%s"), root, wfd.cFileName); //  "Folder\\fileName.extension"
            _tprintf(_T("%s\n"),FileFullPath);
        }

    }while(FindNextFile(hFind, &wfd));

    CloseHandle(hFind);
    hFind=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
int main()
{
    TCHAR Folder[0xFF]=_T("c:\\windows");
    Enum(Folder);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using a for loop...

```
while(1)
    {
        string s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
        string t=s[i]+":\\test";
    TCHAR Folder[0xFF]=_T(t);
    Enum(Folder);
    Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

But this gives me error.. 
error is ::error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     TCHAR Folder[0xFF]=_T(t);
I please request you to look into this

**Result**:Only printing this for a given path
**expected**:I am trying to print all the files names in all the directories in my computer

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Hexadecimal notation can be very useful when dealing with bits, but don't overuse it. If you want an array of `255` elements, then *use* `255`. Slightly related to this: When declaring a function argument using array-like syntax, the compiler still treats it as a pointer. That means e.g. `void Enum(TCHAR root[0xFF])` is compiled as `void Enum(TCHAR* root)`.

Comment: More related to your problem: If you post questions about build errors, then always include the errors in the question. Copy-paste them (as text) into the main question body, in full and complete. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that the `_T` macro is only supposed to be used on *string and character literals*. It's not a universal way to convert anything to a TCHAR string, so `_T(t)` where `t` is a `string` doesn't work.

One simple way to do what you are trying to do in the code above is this

```
string s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
basic_string<TCHAR> folder(_T("X:\\test")); 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) { 
    folder[0] = s[i]; 
    Enum(folder.c_str());
}
```

Just create a string of the right form and replace the drive letter each time round the loop.

Comment: this is giving me error...                                                                                                       in Enum function call ...."Error is  error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'TCHAR* {aka char*}' [-fpermissive]
         Enum(folder.c_str());"

Comment: OK I can see that, change `void Enum(TCHAR root[0xFF])` to `void Enum(const TCHAR* root)`

Comment: You shouldn't really use the array syntax `TCHAR root[0xFF]` for a function parameter, because it's not allowed to have an array as a parameter of a function. Some programmer dude said the same in the comments above.